# How can they call def.then here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jsfiddle

I was reading about promises and found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwebbdesign/NEssP/2/) created by the author of [this post](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt2-practical-use)

The code is here:

```
var def, getData, updateUI, resolvePromise;

// The Promise and handler
def = new $.Deferred();

updateUI = function (data) {
    $('p').html('I got the data!');
    $('div').html(data);
};
getData = $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/html/', 
          data: {
              html: 'testhtml', 
              delay: 3
          }, 
          type: 'post'
    })
    .done(function(resp) {
        return resp;
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        throw new Error("Error getting the data");
    });


// Event Handler
resolvePromise = function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    def.resolve(ev.type, this);
    return def.promise();
};

// Bind the Event
$(document).on('click', 'button', resolvePromise);

def.then(function() {
    return getData;   
})
.then(function(data) {
    updateUI(data);
})
.done(function(promiseValue, el) {
    console.log('The promise was resolved by: ', promiseValue, ' on ', el);
});


// Console output: The promise was resolved by: click on <button> </button>
```

I do understand from the first part of this series that a `deferred` has a `promise` which can be exposed using the `promise method` on it.

Promises have `then method` which returns a `promise` for chaining.

Here they resolve the promise on the deferred in `resolvePromise`,then the then method on the deferred which I dont think is a promise is executed.What am I missing here?

Comment: "Promises have then method which returns a promise for chaining". Hmm, no. The `.promise()` exposes a subset of methods from a `$.Deferred()` object, e.g. `done`, `fail`, `always` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deferred objects in jQuery are also `then`ables and you can use them in place of promises. Doing so is rather uncommon though.

```
var d = $.Deferred().resolve();
d.then(function(){
   console.log("HI"); // this will run.
});
```

The original `$.ajax` having `.done` and `.fail` is pointless in this case, *especially* the `.done` whose return value is ignored and has no impact.

In all honestly, I think the code could be improved to something like rather easily:

```
var getData = $.post('/echo/html/', { html: 'testhtml', delay: 3 }); 

var d = $.Deferred();
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(ev){
    d.resolve();
    return false;
});
$.when(d, getData).then(function(_, data){
    $('p').html('I got the data!');
    $('div').html(data);
});
```

- There is no point in `.then`ing if you only use the identity function (that is, return the same thing and do nothing else.
- There is no point in `.done`ing only to return the same thing.
- Generally, I would advise against promises for handing events unless the events are strictly one time.

Comment: So,in `jQuery` a `deferred` can be used anywhere instead of a `promise` obtained from it using the `promise` method?[Because `deferred.resolve` returns a deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/)So why have a promise at all?

Comment: @user2309862 the key word here is 'thenable', both a jQuery deferred and its promise are _thenable_ meaning they have a `.then` method.  Your assertion is generally correct. Note that _most_ promises should not be obtained from deferreds but rather from chaining previous promises so in fact you should expect to not work with deferreds very often.

Comment: Just wondering - what browsers will you have to support with this code?

Comment: I was reading about `promises` because I use [this library](http://aaronpowell.github.io/db.js/) `db.js` which returns `promises` compatible with `jquery` `promises` which I wanted to chain to perform a series of sequential operations.I have to support most `mobile browsers` and fallback to other means of data retrieval for older browsers.

Comment: The hand rolled promises in `db.js` look quite bad but they'll likely be assimilated correctly. As for the browser question - I asked since new browsers already ship with promises that are better than jQuery's, you can shim them.

Comment: @user2309862 - the difference between a jQuery deferred and a jQuery promise is that only the deferred can be resolved or rejected.  So, you return a promise when you want the outside world to be able to know when it is resolved, but not actually resolve it.  A promise is essentially a subset of a deferred.